# UIImage orientation problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to set manually the orientation of UIImage? Or create with orientation or somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty esoteric thing to want to do. Are you sure there isn't a simpler way to do what you want? (Such as modifying the transform property on the `UIImageView` showing the image.)

To make sure the `UIImage` had a particular orientation, you'd have to fiddle with the Exif tags *before* loading the picture. Open the file, modify the tags, save it, then read it. You can check out the [iphone-exif library](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) for inspiration, but probably need to expand on it.